# Vardump to single variables in php

Tags: php

Lets say I have a function like this:

```
foreach ($links as $link) {
var_dump($link->nodeValue);}
```

And the output looks like this:

string(59) "I was "not" scared" string(32) "Hold my beer!" string(60) "üöä possible episode4" string(43)

So now I want the text behind the string() so I have its like this:

```
echo $first; // I was "not" scared  
echo $second; // Hold my beer!  
echo $third; // I hate strings3000
```

Only way I can think of is fetch var_dump with ob_start(); and substr is somehow...

Comment: Look at http://php.net/manual/en/function.list.php

Comment: It is unclear what you ask. Certainly you can `echo` some variable value, especially if it is f type string. So what is the issue? Don't use `var_dump()`, but use `echo` instead.

Comment: If I understand you correctly, you want to get each $links element into a separate variable?

Answer (score 0):

(If you're on >= 7.0) the following should work for you:

```
$links = [
    (object)['nodeValue' => 'i was "not" scared'],
    (object)['nodeValue' => 'hold my beer'],
]; // just as an input example

list($first, $second) = array_column($links, 'nodeValue');
```

If on < 7.0 `array_column` can't pluck properties of objects so you'd have to gather it yourself with e.g.:

```
$values = array_map(function($node) {return $node->nodeValue;}, $links);
list($first, $second) = $values;
```

Comment: Thank you, I'm on <7.0. What if I don't know the strings before like 'hold my beer' could be something different.

Comment: That doesn't matter, $links declaration is only given for example in the answer.

Answer (score 0):

if I have correctly understood the question you can make a simple function similar to this :

```
function dumper($array){
foreach($array as $value){
    foreach($value as $x){
        echo gettype($x)."(".strlen($x).")". "\n";
        echo $x. "\n";
    }
}
}
```

and then :

```
  $array = [
    (object)['nodeValue' => 'sadasdadasd'],
    (object)['nodeValue' => 'asdasdasdasdasd'],
    (object)['nodeValue' => 'sadasdadasd'],
    (object)['nodeValue' => 'asdasdasdasdasd'],
]; 
dumper($array);
```

That outputs:

```
string(11)
sadasdadasd
string(15)
asdasdasdasdasd
string(11)
sadasdadasd
string(15)
asdasdasdasdasd
```

Comment: What If I dont know the nodeValue .I can not Hardcode it